# multiprocessing.queue and process manager helper class

Tags: python, multithreading, garbage-collection, multiprocessing

I've built a special multiprocessing class designed to manage many XML requests in threads and then shove objects off into queues which get consumed by independent processes.

This generally helps a great deal when data processing (validation and insertion) are a big bottleneck and the API is relatively slow as well.

In testing I find that if the manager class is released by a function then the queue gets garbage collected before the processes have finished.  I don't really want to force the client applications to call a blocking function, but when I read information on the **del**() function it is unclear to me if this would work to block GC until the processes are complete?

Is this the correct approach, or should I force a blocking call that waits for the processes to finish consuming the queue before returning?

Comment: Without any sort of extensive background of what you're trying to do, I'd call the blocking function in a separate thread of the client.

Comment: Messing with the GC will not always give you predictable results...